# How to treat strings with spaces as a whole in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I'd like to build an error handler which will make an empty file marked with the error_occur time.

The core idea is to use the result of `date` command as a parameter.

I did:

```
time_stamp=$(date)
touch $time_stamp
```

But this turns out to create a series of empty file like `2014`, `Wed`, `11:15:20`.

How to convert time_stamp to a whole string here?

Comment: cuonglm and Anthon have both given good answers to your question. But you will make your life simpler by avoiding making files that have spaces (or other special characters) in their names, especially if you want to use bash (and similar shells) with them. It's not hard to handle such file names in bash, but dealing with such names can certainly bloat what could be a simple one line shell command into something that you need to write a proper script for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must double quote your variable:

```
time_stamp="$(date)"
touch "$time_stamp"
```

In this case, double quote in `"$(date)"` is not mandatory, but it's a good practice to do that. You can read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more understanding.

Comment: You do not need quotes on the first line http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131784

Comment: @StevenPenny: Yes, of course, I also noted this in my answer.

Answer (score 15):

cuonglm's answer solves the problem of creating a file with spaces in general, but the problem starts by using the default output from `date`.

If you ever want to use a date or date-time string as part of your file name you should always use the `--rfc-3339` option (if on a recent GNU system) or an appropriate format string. This will give you file names that are sortable in a logical way. The `--rfc-3339` option takes a parameter, use `seconds`, `ns` or `date` depending on the accuracy you want in the filename:

```
time_stamp="$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)"
touch "$time_stamp"
```

You can also get a specific string without any spaces and just the info that you need from `date +FORMAT` (use `man date` for details).

```
time_stamp="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)"
touch "$time_stamp"
```

will give you a file with a name like `20141029-0944` with no spaces and give you the illusion that you don't need to quote. But you still do, as you'd still be invoking the *split+glob* operator which could still actually split if used in a context where `$IFS` has been changed from the default.

Comment: The output of `date --rfc-3339=seconds` still contains spaces, why not `date --iso-8601=seconds` (or just `date -Iseconds`)?

Comment: @nyuszika7h That looks good and works for `date` on my Ubuntu 12.04 box, but neither `man date` nor `date --help` mentions it. So I hope that is good enough an excuse.

Comment: It appears to be undocumented on Debian too, but it's in the man page on Arch Linux. Not sure why.